# OpenCV VideWriter not working after image resize

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, image-processing, video-recording

I am using OpenCV 3 and Visual Studio.
The issue here is that I am unable to save video for any particular resolution other than default full camera resolution.
There is no error, but video file doesn't grow. It stays at 5.54kb.

Here is my code:

```
#include"opencv2\opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

VideoCapture cap_cam1(0);

double Width = cap_cam1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
double Height = cap_cam1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); 
cv::Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(Width), static_cast<int>(Height));
string videoFileName = "D://current.avi";
VideoWriter cam1_write(videoFileName, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'), 10.0, frameSize, true);
Mat image;
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        cap_cam1 >> image;
        resize(image, image, Size(320, 240));
        imshow("image", image);
        cam1_write.write(image);
        if (waitKey(33) == 27)break;
    }

}
```

If I remove the `resize` function, then file size grows and frames are added.
I also tried adding below lines after `VideoWriter` definition

```
cap_cam1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
cap_cam1.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,320);
```

I also tried changing resolution at `VideoWriter` definition, after everything file size remains at 5.54kb.

How to record video at custom resolution?

Comment: Do you confuse 240x320 and 320x240 resolutions?

Comment: instead of `VideoWriter cam1_write(videoFileName, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'), 10.0, frameSize, true);` use `VideoWriter cam1_write(videoFileName, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'), 10.0, cv::Size(320,240), true);` use the target size there (the size you are resizing to)... VideoWriter is only allowed to write one target size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using

```
double Width = cap_cam1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
double Height = cap_cam1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
cv::Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(Width), static_cast<int>(Height));
VideoWriter cam1_write(videoFileName, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'), 10.0, frameSize, true);
```

which means you want to write a video with the VideoCapture image size.

Here you have to change to

```
cv::Size targetSize = cv::Size(320,240);
VideoWriter cam1_write(videoFileName, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'), 10.0, targetSize, true);
```

now in your loop use

```
    resize(image, image, targetSize);
```

That means you have to decide what kind of output image size you want to have when creating the VideoWriter. That's because typical codecs assume constant (known) image resolution.

For setting resolution you have some typo:

```
cap_cam1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
cap_cam1.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,320);
```

this would mean a resolution of `cv::Size(240,320)`, so your code might work if you changed the order there to `cv::Size(320,240)`. See comment of @MBo