# Write frames with non-standard resolution to video in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video-recording

Relating to this question: [OpenCV VideWriter not working after image resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349022/opencv-videwriter-not-working-after-image-resize)

Is it possible to create videos with opencv's `cv2.VideoWriter` that have "non-standard" video resolutions, i.e., non-standard aspect ratios? My code so far:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
video_out = cv2.VideoWriter("video_out.avi", fourcc, 25, (99, 173))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video_in.avi")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame_out = frame[50:50+173,400:400+99]      
    video_out.write(frame_out) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I have tried other video formats (H264, MJPG) as well, no success.

EDIT: No success meaning that the output video gets created, but remains empty. If I use the original frame size the frames do get written to video.

EDIT: Micka's answer works, but I got my python code to run now as well: the boolean argument for coloured video output was missing.

```
   video_out = cv2.VideoWriter("video_out.avi", fourcc, 25, (99, 173), False)
```

Comment: What is the problem here ? "No success" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: many codecs might only support standard values (like width = multiple of 2, 4, 8 or 16) but I think mjpg could work.

Comment: I got it to work with DIVX / XVID as well - it turns out that it is important to set the boolean flag for coloured video at the end of the video writer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, this code does work, but MJPG does round the odd resolution to an even resolution.
H264 did not work with that resolution at all.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // start camera
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    // read a single image to find camera resolution
    cv::Mat image;
    cap >> image;
    if (image.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not find/open camera. Press Enter to exit." << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    cv::Size targetSize(199, 171);
    cv::VideoWriter writer("out.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 25, targetSize, true); // does create a 198x170 video file.
    //cv::VideoWriter writer("out.avi", -1, 25, targetSize, true); // does not work for x264vfw for example with an error message.


    while (cv::waitKey(30) != 'q')
    {
        cap >> image;
        if (!image.empty())
        {
            cv::imshow("captured image", image);

            // resize the actual image to a target size
            cv::Mat writableImage;
            cv::resize(image, writableImage, targetSize);

            writer.write(writableImage);
        }
    }


    // release the camera
    cap.release();
    writer.release();

    std::cout << "Press Enter to exit." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

In general, many codecs are restricted to some pixel-block-constraints like having a multiple of 2, 4, 8, 16 or 32 in each dimension. Either because of the algorithm itself or some hardware instruction optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.VideoWriter("video_out.avi", fourcc, 25, (173, 99))` creates a writer for frames of size 173x99 (width x height).

`frame_out` is a frame of size 99x173 (frame is indexed [y, x]).

Change the indexing to write matching frame sizes.

Comment: oops, I accidentally switched the index for the minimal example. it's correct in the code. so, this did not work, still empty video

Answer (score 0):

In OSX environment:

- OSX: High Sierra (10.13.6)
- Python: 3.6.3
- Open CV (using prebuilt python pck): opencv-python-headless 4.1.0.25

The only combination that worked for me was mp4 wrapper (OSX doesn't love avi) and `mp4v` codec. Also tried `avc1` but it wouldn't write a non standard sized frame

```
codec = 'mp4v'
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*codec)
size = ( 1000 , 500 )
fps = 15
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('filename.mp4', fourcc, fps, size, True)
```