# cv2.VideoWriter cuts out a row of pixels from image stack

Tags: python, opencv

I am using `cv2.VideoWriter()` as an intermediate step in a larger image processing workflow. Basically I have a stack of images that need to be turned into a timelapse, and then the frames in that are processed and then used downstream to mask original imagery. My masking isn't working because array sizes to not correspond with one another, and I've diagnosed the problem to arise from `cv2.VideoWriter()`. My time lapse assembly process came from [here](https://theailearner.com/2018/10/15/creating-video-from-images-using-opencv-python/).

There are a ton of posts about `cv2.VideoWriter()` not working because the frame size is wrong etc. but my problem is not that the video won't write - it's that dimensions of my imagery are being changed. In fact, I'm not even sure if the top row or bottom row is what's being cut off, or if there is some underlying resampling step or something.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

imgs = glob.glob('*.jpg')
img_array = []
for filename in imgs:
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)

size # calling `size` returns (250,187)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project.avi')
mycap = cap.read()
mycap[1].shape # this returns (186,250,3)
```

I would have expected `mycap[1].shape` to have the same attributes as `size` but while `size` indicates I have a 250 pixel wide and 187 pixel tall array, `mycap[1].shape` shows that the video has dimensions 250x186.

Comment: many encoders need width and height to be a multiple of 2,4,8,...

Comment: @Micka - ok, that makes sense and I now see you've addressed this in similar questions [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983996/write-frames-with-non-standard-resolution-to-video-in-opencv). Do you know what happens to the line of pixels that's disappearing? Am I losing the first or last row, or is there some sort of resampling going on?

Comment: I don't know, but I would guess that the bottom rows or right columns will be dropped

Comment: Can you show your input image and what you get+expect on end.

Comment: @Alderven See answer below - I would have expected the two images to look the same but clearly there is more going on than simply cropping the last row or column of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I confirmed that `cv2.VideoWriter()` is not simply clipping an image with odd dimension values, but is instead altering values in the arrays while changing dimensions:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import cv2 as cv

# Create RGB layers
r = np.array([[255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255], [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255], [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255]],dtype=np.uint8)
g = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([[10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 255, 0, 255], [10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 255, 0, 255], [10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 255, 0, 255]],dtype=np.uint8)

# Create a few image layers
rgb1 = np.dstack((r,g,b))
rgb2 = np.dstack((r,g,b))
rgb3 = np.dstack((r,g,b))
rgb4 = np.dstack((r,g,b))

plt.imshow(rgb1)

imgs = [rgb1,rgb2,rgb3,rgb4]

# Create timelapse
img_array = []
for img in imgs:
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)


out = cv.VideoWriter('SO_question.avi',cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()


# Read video in
cap = cv.VideoCapture('SO_question.avi')
cap.read()[1].shape
plt.imshow(cap.read()[1])
```

`plt.imshow(rgb1)` produces the following image:

[image: rgb1 image]

But `plt.imshow(cap.read()[1])` produces the following image:

[image: video image]

Furthermore, using `print(cap.read()[1])` shows that array values are not maintained across the process. Thus, I conclude that a resampling process is occurring (rather than a simple crop step) when width and height are an odd number of pixels.